# ragged right setting in last column creates error in tabular environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

In my document, if I give last column (setted in para mode) as raggedright setting, then LaTeX produces some error, the code is follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array,rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{Similarities/Differences Between Venture Capital and
Angel Investing\label{tab1}}
{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{9pc}>{\raggedright}p{16pc} >{\raggedright}p{16pc}@{}}
\hline
& {Venture Capital} & {Angel Investing} \\
\hline
{Stage of Investment} & Invest in early growth and established companies that have typically have previously received founder, friends and family investment as well as angle investment. & Invest in seed and start-up companies that have previously received founder, friends, and family investment. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please suggest what went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Try `\arraybackslash`.

Comment: Yes, its working fine, can you post this as answer, so I'll accept it...thanks a lot...

Comment: Well, it's already marked as duplicate, so it won't be necessary.